# Eventful API: Search for an event in a city

Tags: php, json, api

I wrote this code to find music events in a city, using Eventful api.

It works for some cities and for other no, and i don't know why.

It should work for all or for nothing.

It works perfectly for Turin, Rome, Florence, Paris, New York, San Francisco, But does **NOT works for Milan and London.**

I mean that with **Milan** I did **not get results**.
The json look  like this:

```
{"last_item":null,"total_items":"0","first_item":null,"page_number":"1","page_size":"10","page_items":null,"search_time":"0.16","page_count":"0","events":null}
```

With **London** instead, I get **different results** from what the site shows.

I don't understand why? Where is the error in my code??

Thank you.

```
$citta=urlencode("san francisco");

$eventiUrl = "http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?app_key=XXX&category=music&location=$citta&sort_order=popularity";

$contents = file_get_contents($eventiUrl);

$eventi=json_decode($contents,true); 

foreach($eventi['events']['event'] as $event){

    echo $event['title']."<br>".$event['description']."<br>";
    echo $event['start_time']." ".$event['stop_time']."<br>";
    echo $event['venue_name']." ".$event['city_name']."<br>";
    echo "<a href=".$event['url'].">link</a><br>";
}
```

Comment: What do you see if you just go to http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?app_key=XXX&category=music&location=london&sort_order=popularity

Comment: If i put my API key instead of XXX i get this: 2017-08-30 00:00:00 
Oslo London
The Libertines & Seasick Steve - OnBlackheath Festival 2017 - Sunday 2017-09-10 00:00:00 
Dartmouth Field London
Vallis Alps  That is different from what the site shows for music in london